# How to Calculate the average tension due to thermal fluctuations (past exam question)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I'm studying for an exam and this is a stat mech question from an old test:

[image]

I feel like there might be a typo but I'm not sure, and want to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong. This is what I've tried:

part i)

By making a force body diagram for the mass in the $ y $ direction, we get the equation: $$ 2F\cos(\theta) = \frac{mv^2}{r} $$ where $ \theta $ is the angle between $ r $ and $ \frac{L}{2} $. Isolating for $ F $ gives us: $$ F(v) = \frac{mv^2L}{4r^2} = $$ We know by the Pythagorean Theorem that $ r^2 = \frac{\ell^2}{4} - \frac{L^2}{4} $ so substituting that into $ F(v) $ gives us:

$$ F(v) = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 \bigg( \frac{2L}{L^2 - \ell^2} \bigg) $$

This would be my solution for part i).

part ii)

We know by the equipartition theorem that $ \frac{1}{2}m \langle v^2 \rangle = \frac{1}{2}fNk_B T $ where $ f $ is the number of degrees of freedom and $ N $ is the particle number. We only have a single particle so $ N = 1 $. Also the problem implies that the particle rotates in a circle of radius $ r $ perpendicular to the horizontal axis, and there's only 1 degree of freedom for a particle moving in a circle so $ f = 1 $. Therefore the equipartition theorem simplifies to:

$$ m \langle v^2 \rangle = k_B T $$

By replacing the factor of $ m\langle v^2 \rangle $ in our solution from part i), we get our solution for part ii)

$$ \langle F \rangle = \frac{L}{L^2 - \ell^2} k_B T $$

I think the numerator should be $ L $ and not $ \ell $ but I'm not positive. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks!